# Change specific text into dots

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#txtField").keyup(function(){
    let data = $(this).val();
  //alert(data);
  let splitData = data.split("-");
  splitData[1] = "****";
  splitData[3] = "*******";
  if($(this).val().length == 19 && $(this).val().indexOf("-") > 0)
    $(this).val(splitData.join("-"));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtField" maxlength="19">
```

**Sample Input**

> ABC-1234-11-1234567

I have this code above as example. But the problem here is that I can still see the 1234 upon inputting a text to the textbox. What I want to achieve here is that when I input the 1234 is it will automatically change into dot `(like the type="password")`.

**Note**

> Sample text above may change but the format is fix. It has three(3) dashes(-)

**Expected Output**

> BLG-****-11- ******

Comment: Are you looking to make every value except the `-` an asterisk? `*`

Comment: @Sean no. Only the 1234 and 1234567 values. the rest is the same

Comment: @Sean sorry My question is not complete. I update it.

Comment: @KiRa your example seems to be working fine. That's what I get `ABC-****-11-*******`

Comment: @Kalimah yes but it replace after the max length is reach.

Comment: @KiRa So you want the replacement to happen as you type?

Comment: @Kalimah yes. Just like matthias_h answer but it replace all the input after the ABC. And even possible it will auto add the hyphen?. Just like the format above.

Comment: I think the best solution is input masking. The issue is that there are many edge cases that comes with caret position retrieval, browser support .. etc. I suggest using a plugin (which is something I rarely do). Here is a start: https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another version you can try, using `RegExp`:

```js
//$('#txtField').on('keyup', function(){ // works
$('#txtField').on('input', function(){   // better
  let s = this.value;
  if (
    /^(.{3}\-.{4}\-.{2}\-)(.{1,7})$/.test(s) ||
    /^(.{3}\-)(.{1,4})$/.test(s)
  ) {
    this.value = RegExp.$1 + RegExp.$2.replace( /./g, '*' );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtField" maxlength="19">
```

And I totally agree with [@User863](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8053274/user863) - using the `input` event is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this using regular expressions:

```js
$("#txtField").keyup(function() {
  let data = $(this).val();
  dots = data.replace(/\d+/g, "*");
  $(this).val(dots);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtField"/>
```

Comment: Sorry this it not what I want to achieve. There I update my question

Answer (score 1):

Using `input` event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event
https://caniuse.com/#search=input%20event

```js
$("#txtField").on('input', function() {
  let data = $(this).val();
  let splitData = data.split("-");
  if (splitData[1])
    splitData[1] = splitData[1].replace(/./g, '*');
  if (splitData[3])
    splitData[3] = splitData[3].replace(/./g, '*');
  $(this).val(splitData.join("-"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txtField" maxlength="19">
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to prevent to use `input` method because its new and not supported in all browsers [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event), this is mostly same to @User863 user's answer, here i have used `keyup` event, this is bit show a character when type in textbox and then after it will be convert into `*`.

```js
$("#txtField").on('keyup', function() {
    let data = $(this).val();
    let splitData = data.split("-");
    if (splitData[1])
        splitData[1] = splitData[1].replace(/./g, '*');
    if (splitData[3])
        splitData[3] = splitData[3].replace(/./g, '*');
    $(this).val(splitData.join("-"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtField" maxlength="19">
```

Comment: Is IE9, a new browser?